# How to check if the email has already been used

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am made a form validation using PHP. If the error happens, the error msg will show around each input column. I would like to check if the email is used or not. So, I used error code to define if input email addr is used, then showing the error message for "The email has been used". However, the result becomes whatever I input, it only shows "The email has been used". Could some help me for this issue? Thanks!

```
<?php
  require_once('./conn.php');
  $errorMsgs = array('nickname'=>'', 'email'=>'', 'password'=>'');
  
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['nickname'])) {
      $errorMsgs['nickname'] = "Please enter your nickname";
    }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    // checking the email is valid or empty
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
      $errorMsgs['email'] = "Please enter your email";
    } else {
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errorMsgs['email'] = "Please enter a valid email";
      }
    }

    $errorCode = $conn->errno;
    if($errorCode === 1062) {
      $errorMsgs['email'] = "The email has been used";
    }

    // checking the password is valid or empty
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $errorMsgs['password'] = "Please enter your password";
    } else {
      if(!preg_match('/\w{8,}/', $password)) {
        $errorMsgs['password'] = "Please enter at least 8 characters";
      }
    }
    
    if(!array_filter($errorMsgs)) {
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO member (nickname, email, password) values ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $_POST['nickname'], $_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result) {
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <title>Message Board - Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container__signup">
    <h1 class="title">Create Account</h1>
    <form class="signup" method="POST" action="signup.php">
      <div>
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="nickname">
      </div>
      <p class="warning__msg"><?php echo $errorMsgs['nickname'];?></p>
      <div>
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
      </div> 
      <p class="warning__msg"><?php echo $errorMsgs['email'];?></p>
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
      </div>
      <p class="warning__msg"><?php echo $errorMsgs['password'];?></p>
      <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" name="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can only read the (duplicate) error code after the query has been done. Or you have to make a sepperate query to check if the email exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the email exists in your user table.
something like this.

```
<?php
  require_once('./conn.php');
  $errorMsgs = array('nickname'=>'', 'email'=>'', 'password'=>'');
  
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['nickname'])) {
      $errorMsgs['nickname'] = "Please enter your nickname";
    }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    // checking the email is valid or empty
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
      $errorMsgs['email'] = "Please enter your email";
    } else {
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errorMsgs['email'] = "Please enter a valid email";
      }
      else{
          //you should use sql parameter binding
     $email = $_POST['email'];
    $checkDuplicate= $conn->query("SELECT email FROM user_table where email = '$email'");
    if(!empty($checkDuplicate)) {
      $errorMsgs['email'] = "The email has been used";
    }
      }
    }
     

    // checking the password is valid or empty
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $errorMsgs['password'] = "Please enter your password";
    } else {
      if(!preg_match('/\w{8,}/', $password)) {
        $errorMsgs['password'] = "Please enter at least 8 characters";
      }
    }
    
    if(empty($errorMsgs)) { //you need to check if there's any error
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO member (nickname, email, password) values ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $_POST['nickname'], $_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result) {
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the resp. May I ask why you add single quote at $email in $checkDuplicate= $conn->query("SELECT email FROM user_table where email = '$email'")? Thank you? If I remove the single quote, the message does not appear, but $email is a string type.

Comment: Yeah, because is a string that's why you have to enclose it in single quote as SQL specification.